# How do I set source and target compatability differently for different source sets in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project that has two source trees (client and main).  The client needs to be compiled to Java 1.7 while main contains Java 1.8 constructs.  I have the following gradle source set defined:

```
sourceSets {
main {
    java {
        srcDir "src/main/java"
        srcDir "src/client/java"
    }
}
    compileMainJava {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
        targetCompatibility = "1.8"
    }

client {
    java {
        srcDir "src/client/java"
    }
}
    compileClientJava {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
        targetCompatibility = "1.7"
    }
}
```

However, the main source set is compiled with 1.7 apparently since I get this

```
:compileJavawarning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
C:\dev\eclipse-ws\generic\IoT-Sound\src\main\java\com\ibm\watson\iot\sound\feature\mfcc\MFCCFeatureExtractor.java:129: error: method references are not supported in -source 1.7
                double[] x = Stream.of(xDataBoxed).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();

(use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)
```

If I comment out the compileMainJava element, then it builds both successfully and seems to compile the client to 1.7 since i get the same warning for compileClientJava (without errors).  I guess this is because I'm using 1.8 jdk, but would like to add these attributes anyway.

So, how do i get main compatibility set to 1.8 and client to 1.7?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to have two language versions in the same `project`.  That said you could have other modules with different Java versions.

In this case you probably want 3 modules

```
:client
:main
:common
```

Now if you want the `project(':client')` to be `Java 7` you can set it in `client/build.gradle`

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Then define your `project(':main')` to be `Java 8` in the `main/build.gradle`

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Just be sure you use `Java 7` in the `project(':common')` or the client won't know how to read the java 8 bytecode generated by `common`.